# Getting the legend of a ggplot show all formats of circles

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I made a ggplot from a dataframe which consists of fish species and their prey species in percentages.

I got the following code to show this in a ggplot:

```
ggplot(Species_TLALL2, aes(factor(StomachSpEng,level = c('NA','Algae', 'Fish eggs','Crab eggs','Chaetomorpha melagonium', 'Copepods', 'Golden grey mullet', 'Atlantic jackknife clam','Baltic macoma', 'Barnacle',
                                                   'Bivalves', 'Blue mussel', 'Bristle worms', 'Catworm', 'Lugworm','Marenzelleria viridis', 'Nematodes',
                                                   'Nereis', 'Phyllodoce maculata', 'Phyllodocida', 'Ragworm', 'Razor clams', 'Sand mason worm',
                                                   'Sandworm','Scoloplos (Scoloplos) armiger','Soft-shell clams','True mussels', 'Chameleon shrimp','Insects','Mosquitoe', 
                                                   'Mysidae', 'Amphipoda', 'Barnacles', 'Idotea balthica', 
                                                   'Idotea granulosa', 'Sand Hopper', 'Sea mats', 'Tubularia','Gastropods','Laver spire shell', 'Crabs','Crustaceans','East Asian shore crab',
                                                   'Edible crab','Flying crab','Isopoda','Shore crab','Swimming crab','Brown shrimp','Common prawn','Grass prawn','Mud shrimp',
                                                   'Shrimps','Skeleton shrimp','Sea-gooseberry','Sprat','Common hermit crab','Sand goby','Plaice','Round goby','Smelt','Herring','Hooknose',
                                                   'Little cuttle','Five-bearded rockling', 'Fish','Righteye flounders','Thick-lipped grey mullet','Greater pipefish','Greater sandeel',
                                                   'Sandeel','Common goby')) 

                            ,factor(SpeciesEng, level = c('Thick-lipped grey mullet','Golden grey mullet','Sprat','Pilchard','Sand goby','Sole','Plaice','Flounder',
                                                                      'Greater pipefish','Round goby','Stickleback','Dab','Herring','Hooknose','Sea trout','Viviparous blenny',
                                                                      'Smelt','Five-bearded rockling','Sea-snail','Bass','Sea scorpion','Scaldfish','Mackerel','Scad','Sand-smelt','Bib','Bull-rout',
                                                                      'Lumpsucker','Twaite shad','Tub gurnard','Greater sandeel','Cod','Garfish','Pollack','Saithe','Whiting','Brill','Lesser weever','Turbot'))
  ,size=Perc, col= Perc))+ geom_point(alpha=.7)+ 
  scale_size_area(max_size=15)+ 
  coord_fixed()+
  #scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0, 3))+
  #scale_y_discrete(expand=c(1, 3))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, vjust=1, size=11, hjust=1))+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(vjust=0.5, size=11, hjust=1))+
  scale_y_discrete(labels = c("Stickleback" = "Stickleback - 3.3", "Flounder" = "Flounder - 3.3", "Sand goby" = "Sand goby - 3.2", "Sole" = "Sole - 3.2",
                              "Thick-lipped grey mullet" = "Thick-lipped grey mullet - 2.6", "Twaite shad" = "Twaite shad - 4.0","Tub gurnard" = "Tub gurnard - 4.0","Greater sandeel"="Greater sandeel - 4.0",      
                              "Garfish" = "Garfish - 4.2","Golden grey mullet" = "Golden grey mullet - 2.8","Greater pipefish" = "Greater pipefish - 3.3",
                              "Herring" = "Herring - 3.4","Hooknose"="Hooknose - 3.4","Scad"= "Scad - 3.7", "Cod" = "Cod - 4.1","Sea scorpion" ="Sea scorpion - 3.6","Scaldfish"="Scaldfish - 3.6",
                              "Mackerel"="Mackerel - 3.6", "Sand-smelt" = "Sand-smelt - 3.7",
                              "Pilchard" = "Pilchard - 3.1","Pollack" = "Pollack - 4.3","Saithe"="Saithe - 4.3","Viviparous blenny" = "Viviparous blenny - 3.5", 
                              "Dab" = "Dab - 3.4","Plaice" = "Plaice - 3.2","Smelt" = "Smelt - 3.5","Sprat" = "Sprat - 3.0","Bib" = "Bib - 3.7",
                              "Turbot" = "Turbot - 4.4","Five-bearded rockling" = "Five-bearded rockling - 3.5","Sea-snail"= "Sea-snail - 3.5","Whiting" = "Whiting - 4.4","Brill"="Brill - 4.4",
                              "Lesser weever"="Lesser weever - 4.4", "Bass" = "Bass - 3.5","Bull-rout" = "Bull-rout - 3.9","Lumpsucker"="Lumpsucker - 3.9", "Sea trout" = "Sea trout - 3.4",
                              "Round goby" = "Round goby - 3.3"))+
  xlab("Prey species in stomachs")+ 
  ylab("Investigated target species")+
  ggtitle("")+
  guides(color = guide_legend(title="Percentages",reverse=TRUE), 
        size = guide_legend(title="Percentages",reverse=TRUE))
```

I have already tried some of the suggestions on stackoverflow...but non of them seem to help.

scale_fill_manual doesnt seem to work and I dont know why

scale_fill_manual(drop = FALSE) doesnt work

Does someone know how to accieve this?

Thank you

Comment: `scale_fill_manual()` will not do anything because you have not mapped any data to the fill aesthetic.

Comment: I will achieve this by addeing: "ggplot(data = Species_TLALL2, mapping = (aes(factor(StomachSpEng,level" right?

Comment: Matthew's comment in other words: for `scale_fill_manual()` to work, you'd need a `fill` argument inside your `aes()`. Instead, you *can* add `scale_color_manual(drop = FALSE)` and `scale_size_manual(drop = FALSE)`.